# PHP Accessing cookie value in html page using jquery+ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I'm trying to access cookie value into html using jquery or ajax ,I'm new to ajax so I don't know how to access `json` values. I tried with `$.getJSON()` but it not working. When I execute same code into `localhost`, it showing `john`.

**test.php**

```
<?php
    $cookie_name = "user";
    $cookie_value = "john";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    echo json_encode($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
?>
```

Comment: Where is the js code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are planning on using the value on the client side, but the issue as to why you are not getting output is the fourth parameter option you have in `setcookie()` function. I'm not sure why you have this as the documentation I found does not list a fourth option. The function accepts the name, value, and time to live.

Also, if all you want to do is return the name of the user value, you don't need to use json_encode(). You can simply echo the name as the response:

```
<?php

     $cookie_name = "user";
     $cookie_value = "john";
     setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30));

     echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];

?>
```